# how to install windows7 on imac 27"

Tags: windows-7

how to install windows 7 on imac without osx and bootcamp

Answer (score 1):

Format the hard drive to FAT32 or NTFS with a MBR partition type.
Insert the Windows DVD.
Hold Option while booting and select the DVD.
Install

Comment: I have done everything but i have black screen

Comment: Is your computer powered on?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MarkM's answer, the 27'' iMac has a problem with the shipped drivers.
Apple has released additional drivers, which can be installed from an USB drive during windows setup.
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3173

It worked for me on a new Windows 7 setup.